# How is this method of solving this problem correct, and what's the correct way to do it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The problem:-
$$ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  2 \\
2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$f(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

find $f(A)$

This is what my books did :-
$$(1-x)f(x)=1+x)$$
$$(I-A)f(A)=(I+A)$$
$$ f(A)=(I-A)^{-1}(I+A)$$

which is equal to
$ A=
(\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$
+
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  2 \\
2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix})^{-1}$
($ 
(\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} +
(\begin{bmatrix}
1&2 \\
2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$)

which can finally be simplified to
$ A=
(\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-1 \\
-1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$)

However, I have many problems with this approach from treating the matrix as if it's an algebraic variable, to randomly converting the 1  to the Identity matrix.

Could someone please explain the correct method to solve such a problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139377/discussion-on-question-by-fhhh-how-is-this-method-of-solving-this-problem-correc).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to consider the characteristic polynomial:
$$
      p(\lambda) = \left|\begin{array}{cc}\lambda-1 & -2 \\ -2 & \lambda-1\end{array}\right| =(\lambda-1)^2-4
$$
Therefore, $(A-I)^2-4I=0$, which implies that $(I-A)^2=4I$ or
$$
               (I-A)^{-1} =\frac{1}{4}(I-A).
$$
Finally,
\begin{align}
       f(A)&=(I+A)(I-A)^{-1} \\
         &= \frac{1}{4}(I+A)(I-A) \\
         &= \frac{1}{4}(I-A^2) \\ 
         &=\frac{1}{4}\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right] -\frac{1}{4}\left[\begin{array}{cc}5 & 4 \\ 4 & 5\end{array}\right] \\
         &=\left[\begin{array}{cc} -1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1\end{array}\right].
\end{align}

Comment: I'm unable t understand what you did. how did you get the determinat equation, and how did you arrive at the next step

Comment: @fhhh : Have you learned about the characteristic polynomial $p$ of a square matrix $A$ and how $p(A)=0$? If not, then don't worry about it

Comment: I don't think I have. Thank you.

Comment: @fhhh : The discussion in your class is probably leading up to that. :)